# Why don't I have 3 uses on Divine Beasts in Botw?

Tags: zelda-breath-of-the-wild

So, I have the EX Champions Ballad DLC and I have battled all Divine Beasts twice and got the + upgrade. However, only Daruk's protection has got 3x uses. Revali's Gale has got 2x, and the other 2 has one each... Really want Urbosa's Fury to be more enhanced... Anyone know what I'm missing here??

Comment: Hi Solveig, welcome to Arqade! As an introduction to this site I suggest [you read this tour](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/help). I must admit that I'm not familiar with the game your asking about, but the way you tell it it sounds to me like it is more of a feature. Why do you think you should be having 3 uses on the item?

Comment: His, Solveig! You're right, you should have 3 uses on each ability (except Mipha's Grace). If you use all of your remaining uses up and wait for the cooldowns to expire, do you get your 3 uses back?

Comment: Omg... Now I feel stupid, haha! This fixed it. I thought I'd already tried this, but I was wrong. Thanks for answer! :-D

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The Divine Beast skills only refresh once you've used up all of the charges.  If you've used Revali's Gale and Urbosa's Fury recently, they will be at ×2 and won't go up back up to ×3 until you use up all of the remaining charges and then wait for the skills to refresh.

Comment: Omg... Now I feel stupid, haha! This fixed it. I thought I'd already tried this, but I was wrong. Thanks for answer! :-D

Comment: @SolveigBoyle make sure you mark it as the answer so the answerer can get credit for it